# .net 6 Blazor WebAssembly Deployed to Azure 400 Error when trying to send email via SendGrid

Tags: azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a basic Blazor WebAssembly project that is using SendGrid to send form data via email. Locally it works fine. I have deployed to Azure App Service and setup API Management as well.

Locally I set an EnvironmentVariable to hold my SendGrid Api key.
This is the EmailService code.

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<Contact>> SendEmail(Contact info)
        {            
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
            var toEmail = _config.GetSection("SendGrid:EmailTo").Value;
            var toName = _config.GetSection("SendGrid:EmailName").Value;
            var _subject = _config.GetSection("SendGrid:EmailSubject").Value;
            
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress($"{info.Email}", $"{info.Name}");
            var subject = _subject;            
            var to = new EmailAddress(toEmail, toName);
            var plainTextContent = info.Message;
            var htmlContent = info.Message;
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<Contact>
                {
                    Data = info,
                    Success = true,
                    Message = "Message has been sent."
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<Contact> { Success = false };

            }

        }
```

In Azure App Service I created an Application setting named "SENDGRID_API_KEY" and it holds the SendGrid API key. I also tried modifying the request before it is sent and added the Authorization header there as well.
When the form submits, it returns a 400 (Bad Request) error.

I do not have a secure certificate on this site yet.

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: If you inspect the `response` body, do you get more information about why SendGrid is returning a 400? Often times the server will include extra information in the response as to why your request was rejected.  

I'm assuming this code is part of your WebAssembly package, thus running on the client browser -- is that right?  If so, are you sure you want to expose your SendGrid key to every client?

Comment: The `response` body is returning the `ServiceResponse` , `{"data":null,"success":false,"message":""}`

On the client side the OnValidSubmit function sends the data to the `EmailService` on the client.

```
public async Task<Contact> SendEmail(Contact info)
        {
            var response = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/email", info);
            return response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<Contact>>().Result.Data;
        }
```
The api is what creates the msg and sends to SendGrid to send. So the key isn't exposed.

Comment: Ok, so the code in your snippet is in fact server side code.  Can you breakpoint or otherwise log the call to SendGrid in your server side API?  From what I see in your code snippet, when the response fails, you are serializing the `ServiceResponse` object with `Success = false`.  Could you also set, say, the `Data` member with the result of `await response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync()` to see what SendGrid is returning?

Comment: Thank you @Dean-Goodman, this gives me some useful information about the error. There is a problem with my verified sender identity with SendGrid.

Comment: That worked.. Apparently because I was using Azure, that is not a verified domain on my SendGrid account. I switched the from address to my verified address and added the user info to the message body.